# example of two linearly independent functions to have a zero Wronskian??

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> What is an example of two linearly independent functions to have a
>   zero Wronskian??

This question is  in reference to http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Wronskian.aspx

Comment: cf. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#The_Wronskian_and_linear_independence).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$ f(x)=x^2$$

$$g(x) = x|x|$$

Note that $$f'(x)=2x$$ while  $$ g'(x)=2x$$ for $x\ge 0$

and $$ g'(x)=-2x$$ for $x\le 0$.

Thus $W(f,g)=0$ for all $x$ while $f$ and $g$ are not linearly dependent on $(-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: I've never seen this before actually. But this $g$ function is not twice differentiable on $\mathbb R$, are there any pair of twice differentiable functions that are linearly independent with zero Wronskian?

Comment: For  a $2\times 2 $ Wronskian, you only need one derivative.

Comment: Yes, but I'm thinking about this is the context of 2nd order ODE's and how we need the Wronskian to be nonzero to form the fundamental set of solutions. So I was wondering if there were exceptions to the standard theorems about this.

Comment: If your functions are solutions to the ODE, then the  Wronskian is 0  iff the solutions are dependent. It is not true for arbitrary functions which are not solutions.

Comment: Ok, I was just mistaken, there are other conditions in the theorems which prevent getting two solutions which are independent with zero Wronskian. But to answer my question, yes, we can find twice differentiable findings with zero Wronskian and are independent. Just integrate the example here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The standard example (due to Peano) are the functions $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x|x|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what $0$ Wronskian of two function means:
$$W(f,g) = f g' - f'g =0$$
On any interval $I$ on which $g\ne 0$ we have
$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)' = \frac{f'g-f g'}{g^2} = 0$$
so on that interval $\frac{f}{g}$ is constant.

So let's take $f$ to be $0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$, and $\ne 0$ on $(0, \infty)$, and $g(x) = f(-x)$. Then $W(f,g) \equiv 0$ but clearly $f$, $g$ are not proportional.  For instance, $f(x) = e^{-\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x> 0$, and $0$ on $(-\infty, 0]$,  $g(x) = e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ for $x<0$ and $0$ on $[0, \infty)$.