# functions whose Wronskian is zero aren't necessarily dependent

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, wronskian

The book gave this exapmle to show that the functions whose Wronskian is zero aren't necessarly dependent:$u_{1}(x)=u_{2}(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $u_{1}(x)=x^{2}, u_{2}(x)=2 x^{2}$ for $x \geq 0$ But what is wrong with their dependence, meanwhile one of them is double of the other one

Comment: Did you quote the example correctly? Could it be that one function is zero for $x<0$ and the other function is zero for $x > 0$?

Comment: Here are more examples: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2733048/42969.

Comment: no Sir I made copy paste the example as it is

Comment: Then it is an error in the book. $1u_2 - 2u_1 = 0$, so those functions are certainly linearly dependent. See my above link for better examples.

Comment: okey, thanks a lot